# Possible mistakes which may result in higher classification accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, text-classification

i am doing text classification with 20NewsGroup data set and i used 20NewsGroup_ByDate dataset. I extract the stemmed documents provided here

http://web.ist.utl.pt/~acardoso/datasets/

i applied tf-idf conversion, Information Gain feature selection and Naive Bayes for classification in weka. My result are higher than the results mentioned on the page mentioned above(82%). I have thought alot and search the possible mistakes i may made but could'nt find out any as 
i am using their processed documents.

I only need to apply tf-idf,IG and classifier. Kindly provide me insights what could be possible mistakes which can result in higher accuracy than expected ?

Comment: Have you trained it on the provided data and then tested on the same data?

Comment: @sashkello no  both datasets are seperated in different directories. i used the last part like 20NG-train-stemmed for training classifier and 20NG-test-stemmed for testing classifier performance.

Comment: You applied feature selection and used a TF-IDF term weighting scheme. This resulted in a 1%ish performance gain over the reported result, which presumably did neither. I think that's all the explanation you need (indeed that's a small enough difference that I think random feature selection could lead to the same conclusions)

Comment: @BenAllison, thanx for passing through, i have also applied this option like not apply tf-idf and IG but still accuracies are high i.e. for svm it is giving me accuracy of 99%. I have tried one selection by not applying(skipping) the point 1.5 as mentioned on the provided link i.e. "The title/subject of each document is simply added in the beginning of the document's text." and it gives me result for svm much closer to the results provided on the link i.e. 80.9 (approx 81% for svm where results provided are 82.8%). I think that author missed that point.

Comment: Right---there are so many parameters in an implementation (pre-processing, hyper-parameters, etc) that being within a % or two given incomplete information sounds plausible